# Throw exception to stop process

Tags: c#, exception

Some times in C# I would like to throw an exception that cannot be handled.  An escalated exception that results in the process being stopped.  Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you simple throw an exception and force the process to be closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about simply closing the process like this:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Close();
```

Comment: `.Close(` is a part of `.Dispose()` and has nothing to do with ending a Process . the following ends a Process, but has noticeable limitations compared to `throw` -- `Environment.Exit(Int32)` .

Comment: i guess you meant `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()`

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like:

```
class BadassException : Exception
{
  public BadassException(string message)
  {
    Environment.FailFast(message);
  }
}

...

throw new BadassException("Erk!!!");
```

Comment: +1 Just for the total abuse of the throw syntax. Clearly a badass exception.

Comment: I think this is a coding horror.  Exceptions should not have any logic buried in them.  Exceptions are thrown and then it is up to the catch block to determine what kind of logic to perform depending on the type of exception.  Throw your BadAss exception, but let the catch block  do the Environment.FailFast.

Comment: @Jon Raynor: I agree with you, but the OP did not ask for that. I just gave what was asked for :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want an exception to be handled, don't handle it.

Answer (score 2):

That's not an exception, that's an atomic bomb.

Seriously though, there are better ways of handling this scenario. If you're looking to terminate your process look at options like [Application.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible because every exception must inherit from the `Exception` base class, and you can do a `catch(Exception)`.

However, as others have pointed out, you can fail fast. You can also throw exceptions that cannot be caught specifically, like so:

```
public class MyLibraryClass
{
    private class MyException : Exception { ... }

    public void MyMethod() { throw new MyException(); }
}
```

Then the caller cannot do a `catch(MyException exc)`, only a `catch(Exception exc)`. But still, that means the exception can be caught.

Comment: The CLR supports throwing objects that are not `Exception`. With a little hand rolled IL, you can easily throw just about anything. IIRC, those will only be caught with `catch { }`.

Answer (score 0):

Any exception that is not handled will stop your application.  Usually applications have an application or top level exception handler that catches any unhandled exceptions, does any data maintenance and shuts down the application gracefully.

In your case, I think the best approach is to create a new exception that derives from exception class called something like StopApplicationException.

Then whenever you need to stop your application, throw this type of exception.  In your catch block further up the call stack:

```
catch (StopApplicationException)
{
  //Stop your application
}
catch (ArgumentNullException)
{
  //Null Exception Logic goes here...
}
catch  ...And so forth
```